# How does an algebraic curve correspond to a branch covering of the rational points of the projective line?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, covering-spaces

I am trying my best to understand Lemma 8.4 of [arXiv:1602.03662](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03662).

In particular, the sentence " let $\phi: C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{Q}}^1$
be the branch covering corresponding to $F/\mathbb{Q}(Y)$".

What is $C$? My assumption was that it is the algebraic curve defined by $f(X,Y)=X^m-X^{m-1}-Y$. If I am correct, then what, concretely, does $\phi$ do with the points of $C$, and how does it cover $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{Q}}^1$?

In Serre's "Topics in Galois Theory", Chapter 4 starts with this paragraph:

> Let $\,E\,$ be a finite Galois extension of
> $\,\mathbb{Q}(T)\,$ with group $\,G\,$ which is
> *regular*, i.e.,
> $\,\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\cap E=\mathbb{Q}.\,$
> Geometrically, $\,E\,$ can be viewed as the
> function field of a smooth projective curve
> $\,C\,$ which is absolutely irreducible over
> $\,\mathbb{Q}\,$; the inclusion
> $\,\mathbb{Q}(T)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}_1\,$
> defined over $\,\mathbb{Q}\,$ with Group $,G

Though this just confused me more, because $f(X,Y)$ is not homogeneous, so $C$ wouldn't be a projective curve.

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0RWs.png

Comment: $[X:Y:1]\to [Y:1]$ that extends to $[x:y:z]\to [y:z]$ on the projective closure $x^m-z x^{m-1}-z^{m-1}y=0$

Comment: For $D:Y^3=X^2$ then $(X,Y)\to Y/X$ is a rational map $D\to \Bbb{P}^1$, on the projective closure it becomes $[X:Y:1]\to [Y:X]$ still not a morphism at $[0:0:1]$, but it comes from a morphism $E\to \Bbb{P}^1$ where $E$ (which is just $\Bbb{A}^1$, with function field $\Bbb{Q}(t), t=X/Y,(X,Y)=(t^3,t^2)$) is the smooth projective curve whose function field is the same as $D$

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BXX